# PostgreSQL PostGIS Query is taking long time

Tags: postgis, postgresql, performance

I have a table that included only 472 rows and geometry of table is Multipolygon. I am sending query to database via **PgAdmin III**

```
select * from mytable // this query takes 99413 ms
```

This is a very long time.

What do you think about long queries on PostgreSQL? Server resource, disc, CPU etc.

Comment: Maybe it's not the query issue, but data sending time. Try to execute select 1 from mytable - you'll get time closest to time of execution

Comment: When asking such things you should do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) and post result using http://explain.depesz.com/. However in your case the answer is probably: You have few rows but the geoms are huge so it takes a lot of time to send the results to you.

Comment: How long does it take to return just one row of the table?

Comment: You need to figure out whether the time is spent reading the table (`explain analyze`) or sending the rows to the client.

Comment: It's not possible to review the quality of your server resources if you don't provide them.  You also don't provide key information about the column values (especially number of vertices per feature) and the size and source of the data.  Please **edit** the question.